# REGEXP_LIKE to find a string with only one word with any number of characters

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex that will select fields that have only one word.

something like....

```
    SELECT songtitle
    FROM music
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(songtitle, '+[^\s]')
```

I want it to function similar to how the following would:

```
    WHERE songtitle NOT LIKE('% %');
```

songtitle:

Hey Jude

Help!

Strawberry Fields Forever

Blackbird

Woman

The expression should select records 2 4 and 5.

Please, point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly simpler variation on Marcin's answer assuming that the usual \S class is available... `^\S+$`

http://regexr.com?33v62

It seems to hit your test cases properly, but if \S isn't available, use Marcin's

Answer (score 1):

The regex may look like

`^[^\s]+$`

However you should consider changing regex to [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',songtitle) = 0
```

Comment: The CHARINDEX function works great, but I'm really looking for how to do it with regex.  Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: The regex I've posted should do the work as well. Did you check it?